# Fixed length string in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to set the length of a field in EF (6.1)?

I want the following property to be generated as `char(2)`:

```
public string LanguageId { get; set; }
```

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.10

Comment: If you want `char` you need to specify it explicitly because AFAIK by default EF uses `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could combine `TypeName` and `StringLength`:

```
[Column(TypeName = "char")]
[StringLength(2)]
public string LanguageId { get; set; }
```

Within SQL Server it should generate a `char(2)` column.

Comment: Any idea if there's a more database-agnostic approach these days?